# How to localize autorun.inf?

Tags: windows, localization, autorun

Has anyone successfully created a single page autorun.inf file? The documentation for *.inf files would suggest that

```
[autorun] 
open="MyApp.exe"
icon=MyApp.exe,0
label=%AppLabel%
action=%AppAction%
[Strings]
AppLabel = "My test app"
AppAction = "Start my test app"
[Strings.0407]  ; 0407 is the language ID for German
AppLabel = "German my test app"
AppAction = "German start my test app"
```

should work. I find that label (as it appears in the Autorun dialog) shows '%AppLabel%' rather than the expected 'My test app'.

Comment: Where did you read that you could use variables like that? At least the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144200%28VS.85%29.aspx) don't mention any such support.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547485(VS.85).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547485(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144200%28VS.85%29.aspx) linked by Casablanca in a comment tell how this must be done, however in a roundabout way.

The answer is in ["indirect strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759919%28VS.85%29.aspx). You must add multiple string resources to an EXE or DLL file, all with the same ID but different languages specified (by the `LANGUAGE` statement.) You can then reference those strings in the `autorun.inf` file by the indirect string syntax: `@filename,-id`

The syntax for indirect strings is an `@` sign, followed by the name of the file containing the string resources you are referencing, followed by a comma, a minus, then the string ID you are referencing.

Example:

```
[autorun]
open="MyApp.exe"
icon=MyApp.exe,0
label=@MyApp.exe,-100
action=@MyApp.exe,-101
```

This requires you to have a string table resource in your EXE containing all the localised strings. It can look like this in the RC file format:

```
#include <winresrc.h>

LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    100 "English MyApp
    101 "English MyApp description text"
END

LANGUAGE LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    100 "German MyApp
    101 "German MyApp description text"
END
```

Windows should then use the German string if the user has a German language version of Windows installed, or selected German as his MUI language. Any other language version should pick the English strings.

Comment: I could not get this to work for the label string. The documentation for autorun.inf only mentions the indirect strings technique for the action string, which worked fine; so I don't think it is possible to localize the label.